# Changing the docker data directory to a non root location changes the disks name

Tags: docker, ubuntu, diskspace, datadirectory

**High-level goal**:
I want to build the [carla-simulator in a docker environment](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_docker_unreal/).

**Low-level goal**:
My root file system does not have enough disk space. Therefore, I changed my docker data directory from `/var/lib/docker/` to my internal HDD mounted at: `/media/<username>/HDD` into the folder `/media/<username>/HDD/docker/` which I created prior to changing my `daemon.json` in `/etc/docker/`. I followed this guide to achieve this modification https://www.guguweb.com/2019/02/07/how-to-move-docker-data-directory-to-another-location-on-ubuntu/.
This worked well until I rebooted.

**My Problem**:
Everytime I reboot, the name of my mounted HDD is incremented. After the first reboot, the name changed from `HDD` to `HDD1`, after the second reboot from `HDD1` to `HDD2`. This caused many problems and I am unable to relocate my docker data directory.

Removing the `data-root` specification from the `daemon.json` removed this problem, but I would like to relocate my docker data directory.

**Suspected reasons**:
Maybe the docker deamon starts looking for the internal HDD before ubuntu mounts the drive. But I don't know what I could do to fix my problem.

**Software in use**:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Docker 20.10.15
- HDD Partion as Ext4